# Optional output file in console application - make StreamWriter global

Tags: c#

I'm writing a console application which is looking up information about SSIS packages in SQL Server.  I have it working and writing to a .csv file.  I just added in the ability to pass command line switches for servername, foldername and outputfile.  If an output file is not specified, I'd just like to output to the console, which I'm already doing.

The way I've handled the file writing seems awkward, and is probably wrong.

In my main method I create a StreamWriter.  I need to write the entire output of the program to this file.  I explore folders under my specified folder by recursively calling a function.

I pass the StreamWriter object along in all calls - it is a parameter in functions which don't use it, so it can be passed to the one that does.  It seems like I should be able to make it a global variable, but I see that c# doesn't have globals and "if you are using a global, you are probably doing it wrong".

I'd planned on revisiting this issue eventually after plugging away at this little utility for a while, but I now have the problem that all the functions want the StreamWriter object - and if I make it optional, then it won't be there for the functions.  And it also seems c# doesn't do optional arguments.

I'm sure you can tell I'm no c# expert and only dabble when I need to.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern to refer to the StreamWriter you're using.  The singleton is a way to "simulate" the functionality of global variables, without having the problems of them.

Essentially, what the singleton provides is a class-specific instance of a resource you want to be shared among many different parts in your application.  The resource is accessed through the a static class instance.

Effectively, what you'll want to do is to define a class which has as a public **static** member the StreamWriter that you'll want to use; in that way, any method that you use in the rest of your code can get access to that SAME instance of the StreamWriter by accessing it from the containing class (without needing to create an instance of the class, because it's static).

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
public static class CsvWriter
{
   private static StreamWriter _writer = new StreamWriter(...);

   public static  StreamWriter Writer 
   {
      get { return _writer; }
   }
}
```

Some variation is possible, the main item is the static property here. It's like a global but not (entirely) as bad.

Comment: Hi Henk.  I'm getting this error on the new StreamWriter() spot.

No overload for method 'StreamWriter' takes '0' arguments.  I've tried following templates from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx and get the same result.

Comment: Yeah, I should have put dots in there... Use a Filename or a Stream to construct the StreamWriter. You probably have something already.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with what is probably obvious :)

Comment: How to you refer to this object?  Is it automatically created?  I've tried using new, but it says I can't create an instance of a static object.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just use the classname instead of an object: CsvWriter.Writer. Note that System.Console is static class too.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the functions of the same class? You can make a class variable (a field) and access it from all the methods of the class. If not you can always create a new public class with a static field.

Answer (score 0):

I you can use [`Console.SetOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) for this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\path\file.ext");
    try
    {
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        Console.WriteLine("Two");
        Console.WriteLine("Three");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That went wrong.");
    }
    finally
    {
        writer.Dispose();
    }    
}
```

Comment: That's cool, but my console output is formatted to be readable, while the file output is csv.